# how to get the row number of the datarow object in for each loop

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

I am using the vb.net 2013 
I am looping through for - next statement
here dt is datatable

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

' here i want the row number (row_number) of the row being processed
' so that i can update some values in the previous row of datatable dt
' something like 

dt(row_number-1)(0) = 50

Next
```

any help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different loop:

```
    For rowNum = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        dt(rowNum - 1)(0) = 50
    Next
```

Comment: It works ! I want to know that weather using experssion dt.Rows.Count - 1 will be evaluated in every loop. If we declare a variable in advance holding the value of dt.Rows.Count - 1 and using the varaiable here might be better for larger tables. Thanks for this nice, working and small snippet.

Comment: It is only evaluated at the head of the loop. In fact, if you establish the loop like that and then inside the loop, you sometimes delete members of the tr.Rows collection, when you get to the end of the loop, you'll experience index outofbounds exceptions. So you have to take precautions in some cases, but everything in programming is like that.

Comment: Your ( @clweeks ) answer is help full me to know that  the loop variable are only evaluated at the head of the loop. but at the same time it raised a doubt that for the situations you have pointed out (the rows are deleted or added in the table variable) the loop iterations will skip those changes. How those changes will be incorporated if the loop variable are only evaluated at the head of the loop.

Comment: You can monkey with rowNum as much as you want. So if you're iterating across the collection of rows, checking for certain things and occasionally deleting a row, each time you delete the row, you can "rowNum -= 1" to keep the loop's counter consistent. There are other times when what you do is create a list of datarows before the loop and copy the rows you want to remove into the list and then in a second loop, delete rows in the list from the datatable. It all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a good old index variable:

```
Dim row_number as integer = 0
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

    ' here i want the row number (row_number) of the row being processed
    ' so that i can update some values in the previous row of datatable dt
    ' something like 

    dt(row_number-1)(0) = 50
    row_number += 1
Next
```

Comment: It works ! but my requirement is 
I have two numeric fields (fldNum1, fldNum2) and a date field fldDate in a datatable order by date field
I want to put the cummulative (sum from previous dates gets added) sum of the fldNum1 in the fldNum2 on the last record for a date. (There can be any records for a date.)
How could i do this in code. The datarow loop was for this function.

Comment: Just declare another variable of the type you need outside the loop and add to it each time through.